# Where's all the punctuation gone in my variable?

Tags: actionscript-3

As a newbie to Flash/AS3 I'm puzzled.
My dilemma: I have a variable that holds a string which populates a text field. The text includes commas, fill stops, question marks and the like. When I run my movie everything is hunky dory and everything displays as it should.Cool!
I created a tooltip with multiple tips held in an array. I pass a variable param in the event handler to let it know which tooltip text to display. However, when I run my movie and mouse over my icon to display the tooltip everything is there except for the punctuation. Confused!

```
var somevar = " Here's my text, just as I want it to display. Cool!" works like a charm.

var tipArray:Array = new Array();
    tipArray[0] = "By providing some text, especially here, there is no chance the punction displays! what's happening?"


function getToolTip(i:int):Function {
        return function(e:MouseEvent):void {
                //creating a new tooltip instance
                var tooltip:Tooltip = new Tooltip();
                //we tell the holder to hold our tooltip
                holder = tooltip;
                holder.tip.background = true;
                holder.tip.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFCD;
                holder.tip.border = true;
                holder.tip.borderColor = 0x000000;
                holder.tip.textColor = 0x333333;

                holder.tipHeading.background = true;
                holder.tipHeading.backgroundColor = 0x999999;
                holder.tipHeading.border = true;
                holder.tipHeading.borderColor = 0x000000;
                holder.tipHeading.textColor = 0x333333;
                holder.tipHeading.text = tipTitleArray[i];
                holder.tipHeading.setTextFormat(headingOne);

                holder.tip.autoSize = "right";
                holder.tip.width = 180;
                holder.tipHeading.width = 180;
                holder.tip.multiline = true;
                holder.tip.wordWrap = true;
                holder.tip.text = tipArray[i];
                trace(holder.tip.text);
                Vpadding = holder.height;
                holder.tipHeading.y = holder.tip.y-holder.tipHeading.height;

                //positioning the tooltip on the stage
                holder.x = stage.mouseX- Hpadding;
                holder.y = stage.mouseY - Vpadding;
                trace ("holder Y after setting: " + holder.y);

                //adding the tooltip to the stage 
                addChild(tooltip);
                };
        }
```

The output I get in the tooltip is 
By providing some text especially here there is no chance the punction displays whats happening

Can anyone explain why one works and the other doesn't?

Comment: Probably a font issue. What kind of font are you using? If it is not _sans, it should be embedded.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I checked and the font is the same on both counts, its Calibri which is a pretty standard font.

Comment: Embed it. Add .embedFonts = true; on your textfield instance and in your textformat pass new Calibri().fontName when specifying textformat.font. //-> where "Calibri" would be the linkage name

Comment: The crazy thing is that when I trace what the text box holds it gives me all the punctuation. It's so weird

Comment: Once again - have you embedded your font? You need to embed all the fonts except of sans.

Comment: I embedded the font via the library panel and it worked. This is great as a work around but does increase the size of my file. Why do we have to do this for one instance and not the other?

Comment: Custom fonts will only be used if they are on the device Flash is running from. And it has some caveats to it (can't animate it, can't transform it, can't apply any effects, etc). Additionally, not all characters will load. This is all done for memory purposes, I believe, or security related issues. Embedding is the way to get around this. If you use any font not named `sans` or `serif`, you **must** embed them. It's good practice regardless since it guarantees the font is correct (and no one has messed with the font file)

Comment: Josh, thanks for the explanation. It make sense but what a palava. You'd think that with all the resources Adobe have they could have come up with something better than this... Thanks anyway. and thanks to Fygo too, a great help

Comment: @user2938700 There is no better option. This allows all devices to use the same font, regardless of what is installed. It is done this way for both memory-sake and appearances-sake. Yes, it adds a bit of size to your file but that's the cost of using a custom font, no matter what the situation (using one on the web requires the browser to download the entire font, for example, so there is zero difference)